# Convert MonthName-Year to Year-MonthNumber

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, sql-server-2008

I have a custom date string in SQL. I need to convert the date into custom format. Below is the example for it.

```
SQL Input : 'January-2019' (Month Name-Year format)
Output    : '201901'       (Year-Month Number format, Month Number must be two digit)
```

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try this.

```
DECLARE @input  AS VARCHAR(20) = 'January-2019'
Select Convert(Varchar(6), Cast(Replace(@input, '-', ' 01 ') as DATE), 112)
```

[**Live Demo**](https://rextester.com/PHZ29222)

Answer (score 4):

Since you're using SQL 2008 you can use [`CONVERT(DATE, ...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) + [`CONVERT(VARCHAR, ...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
DECLARE @input  AS VARCHAR(20) = 'January-2019'
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), CONVERT(DATE, '01-' + @input), 112)
```

Note that you need to prepend `01-` to the string.

Comment: @saket replace `@input` the name of column that contains the value such as February-2019, December-2018 etc

Comment: Thanks for comment.